# How to use script parametr(folder path) as a variable?

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to write a script which can delete all 0 size files. I already have command to do this - `find . -size 0 -type f -delete`. The problem is that I want to use 1st script parametr as a path. I had sth like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1/$(find . -size 0 -type f -delete)
```

error: syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -size 0 -type f -delete
```

You can also do:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$1" && find . -size 0 -type f -delete
```

Comment: Thank you for your answear but can you explain me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: @masterllama a couple of things: a) if `$1` contains spaces, each word will be handled separately, causing a syntax error - which is why I quoted it; and b) `$( )` is used to get the output of a command, and `find` will not produce any output here, so in the end you're trying to run `$1/` which will also give an error.